# I want to trace logs using a Macro multi parameter always null. problem c++ windows

Tags: c++, windows, logging, macros

I am using the following way to cout a function's time:

```
#define TIME_COST(message, ...)\
 char szMessageBuffer[2048] = {0};\
 va_list ArgList;\
 va_start(ArgList, message);\
 vsprintf_s(szMessageBuffer, 2048, message, ArgList);\
 va_end(ArgList); \
 string strMessage(szMessageBuffer);\
 CQLogTimer t(strMessage);
```

// CQLogTimer is a self destructor,which will cout life time of its own and print szMessageBuffer.
However when I use the macro this :

```
void fun
{
TIME_COST("hello->%s", filePath);
XXXXXX
}
```

The message generated always is hello->(null)

Can Any one help?
Many thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a macro (and why are you using variable arguments)? There certainly are safer ways to do logging.

Comment: because I want to clean it in release mode totally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct version is:

```
#define TIME_COST(message, ...)\
 char szMessageBuffer[2048] = {0};\
 sprintf_s(szMessageBuffer, 2048, message, __VA_ARGS__);\
 string strMessage(szMessageBuffer);\
 CQLogTimer t(strMessage);
```

`__VA_ARGS__` is not `va_list` type, but comma-separated arguments, so you need to use `sprintf_s`, not `vsprintf_s`.

Answer (score 2):

A different approach to logging is to use streams:

```
#define LOG( msg )     \
  {                    \
     ostringstream os; \
     os << msg;        \
     CDLogTimer( os.str() ); \
  }
```

You can then say things like:

```
LOG( "the value of x is " << x << " and of y is " << y );
```

Comment: I never liked this stream-style syntax and don't know why. Nevertheless your version looks much neater, than the one with sprintf_s.

Answer (score 1):

Macros are not variadic functions, you don't need to process argument list with `va_*` functions. Macros just transform the text of the source code.

With that said, your compiler (MSVC I assume) supports variadic macros with `__VA_ARGS__`:

```
#define TIME_COST(fmt, ...)\
 char szMessageBuffer[2048] = {0};\
 sprintf_s(szMessageBuffer, 2048, fmt, __VA_ARGS__);\
 string strMessage(szMessageBuffer);\
 CQLogTimer t(strMessage);
```

Comment: Assuming TIME_COST("hello->%s", filePath) call, your code wont compile - error C2664: 'int vswprintf_s(wchar_t *,size_t,const wchar_t *,va_list)' : cannot convert parameter 4 from '<type of the filePath parameter>' to 'va_list'

Comment: @AOI Karasu, yeah, missed that one.