# get function parameter like streamstring

Tags: c++

i want get to function  parameter like streamstring

// Declartion
foo (std::stringstream strString);

// Using
foo("Hello" << "world");

how to do that??

Comment: First, you'd have to get your strange string concatenation (?) `"Hello" << "world"` to work; why not replace this by something along the lines of `std::string("Hello") + std::string("world")`? Then you would declare a function `foo` that takes a `std::string` as its argument.

Answer (score 2):

The `<<` syntax used for stream insertion is achieved by the various stream classes overloading the left-shift operator (that's what the `<<` is).  You can overload the left shift operator for your class:

```
struct Example
{
    Example& operator<<(int i) 
    {
        /* use i */ 
        return *this; 
    }
};

Example e;
e << 42; // calls operator<< overload
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a macro - see this answer [I want to trace logs using a Macro multi parameter always null. problem c++ windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027729/i-want-to-trace-logs-using-a-macro-multi-parameter-always-null-problem-c-windo/3027897#3027897)